# Center of gravity of a regular polygon

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How do I prove that the origin is the [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) of the regular polygon whose vertices are the solutions of the equation $z^n=1$ in the complex plane?

Comment: Not sure why this question is getting downvoted.

Comment: How do you define "gravity center"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular polygon is rotationally symmetrical about the origin by angle $ \frac{ 2\pi}{n} $.

What point do you know is invariant under rotation about the origin by any (non-zero) degree?